# Chrome Console getElementsByClassName undefined

Tags: jquery, google-developers-console

Estoy intentando armar una query básica con la consola de Chrome, sin embargo obtengo como resultado "undefined" cada vez. La función es la siguiente:

```
function prices() {
  var price_spans = document.getElementsByClassName("woocommerce-Price-amount amount");
  return (price_spans[1].text())
}
```

Estoy completamente seguro de que el elemento existe y también he intentado directamente con `return price_spans` pero también me devuelve undefined. El objetivo de la función es utilizarla como variable en GTM.

Comment: ¿Esa función se ejecuta después de que se carga el contenido del DOM?

Comment: ¿Existe esa etiqueta de clase?

Comment: Los arrays en Javascript SIEMPRE empiezan en 0

Comment: No puedes llamar a una clase "woocommerce-Price-amount amount", ya que esta contiene un espacio, trata de cambiar por "woocommerce-Price-amount-amount" o simplemente "woocommerce-Price-amount"